# Warning message Attempting to create USE_BLOCK_IN_FRAME variable with block that isn't in the frame

Tags: iphone, ios5, xcode4.2

When setting `exception breakpoint` and debugging getting warning message that Catchpoint 2 (exception thrown).Current language:  auto; currently objective-c
warning: Attempting to create `USE_BLOCK_IN_FRAME` variable with block that isn't in the frame.
(gdb)

What does it means.

In my case in the mainviewcontroller on UIToolbar have plapause toggle button which when hits plays audio file and loads 20 view controllers one after the other by using perform selector

```
-(void)playpauseAction:(id)sender 
{

 if  

  ([audioPlayer isPlaying]){

 [sender setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"play.png"] forState:UIControlStateSelected];

 [audioPlayer pause];

  } else {

 [sender setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"pause.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];

 [audioPlayer play];

 [self performSelector:@selector(displayviewsAction:) withObject:nil afterDelay:11.0];

  }  

}

- (void)displayviewsAction:(id)sender
{
FirstViewController *viewController = [[FirstViewController alloc] init];

viewController.view.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 480);

[self.view addSubview:viewController.view];

[self.view addSubview:toolbar];

[self performSelector:@selector(secondViewController) withObject:nil afterDelay:23];

[viewController release];

}

-(void)secondViewController {
SecondViewController *secondController = [[SecondViewController alloc] init];

secondController.view.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 480);

[self.view addSubview:secondController.view]; 

[self.view addSubview:toolbar];

[self performSelector:@selector(ThirdviewController) withObject:nil afterDelay:27];

[secondController release];
}
```

When simply try to run the application in simulator it works fine but when debug with exception breakpoint and hits play button to start debugging gets this warning message.

Anyone have ideas what is going on with exception breakpoint.

Answer (score 2):

It's a warning from the debugger,when it could not create any info struct for a particular object.

Here is an example :

```
NSString* string = [[NSString alloc] initWithUTF8String:line];
```

in this line of code the method initWithUTF8String: expects an UTF-8 encoded C string and not a NSString object.
so this time complier will give an warrning of `USE_BLOCK_IN_FRAME`.

We should to insure that all warrnings are resolve ,because it can be big error or app may crashed in near future .

---

> Update:

---

```
-(void)playpauseAction:(id)sender 
{

    UIButton *btn = (UIButton *)sender;
      if([audioPlayer isPlaying]){

     [audioPlayer pause];   

     [btn setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"pause.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];

      } else {

     [audioPlayer play];
     [btn setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"play.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];



 [self performSelector:@selector(displayviewsAction) withObject:nil afterDelay:11.0];

  }  

}

- (void)displayviewsAction
{
FirstViewController *viewController = [[FirstViewController alloc] initWithNibName:"FirstViewController"];

viewController.view.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 480);

[self.view addSubview:viewController.view];

[self.view addSubview:toolbar];

[self performSelector:@selector(secondViewController) withObject:nil afterDelay:23];

[viewController release];

}

-(void)secondViewController {
SecondViewController *secondController = [[SecondViewController alloc] init];

secondController.view.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 480);

[self.view addSubview:secondController.view]; 

[self.view addSubview:toolbar];

[self performSelector:@selector(ThirdviewController) withObject:nil afterDelay:27];

[secondController release];
}
```

Comment: So then how to fix this warning

Comment: make sure all the method and objects you are using are proper and correct, like if you are using textfield or table view methods first make sure that all delegates are import in .h file <UITableViewDelegate,UItextFieldDelegate> , than If you are using tham from IB than create IBOutlet and property while you are using some geter or setter method on them and synthisize them in .m too.

Comment: I am not at my system so i can not check now every thing , i will reply u on tomorrow by morning, while u can check ur code in my reply with update ...